# Vim key sequence for editing git-rebase-todo

Tags: vim, git-rebase

Suppose I want to squash a bunch of commits via interactive rebase `git rebase -i HEAD~4`

```
pick afecc5edbc5 lighten wording on menu
pick b652f76b10f changelog
pick a636683fea4 blah
pick cafc0f09b62 Updated changelogs
```

When I position the cursor at second "pick" I press `cws` and now we're looking at

```
pick afecc5edbc5 lighten wording on menu
s b652f76b10f changelog
pick a636683fea4 blah
pick cafc0f09b62 Updated changelogs
```

For the rest of them I need to `<esc><down><left>cws`

The additional requirement of `<esc>` takes this procedure from doable to tedious. Is there a better way to edit `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo`?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @caduceus You can use dot-command. Or record and repeat a macro. Or use search/replace/substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using `:help .` instead of repeating `cws`:

```
cws<Esc>
<Down>
.
<Down>
.
```

Or, if all the `pick`s you want to change are contiguous, you could use visual-block mode:

```
<C-v>e
<Down>
<Down>
cs<Esc>
```

Or, again if the `pick`s are contiguous, you could use a substitution:

```
:,4s/^pick/s<CR>
```

There are other ways.